# How the call setValue() and handle submit function under the same event?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The example is given below
I want both come under single event onChange

```
<input type="text" onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} onKeyPress={(handleSubmit)} />
```

Comment: Show what's inside `handleSubmit`

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Simple like this:

```
<input type="text" onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value); handleSubmit(); } />
```

Comment: e => setValue(e.target.value); at this semicolumn its showing error "expected  }"

Comment: If you go this route, your `handleSubmit` function may not have the newest value state at the time it's called because it's not a synchronous operation.

Comment: @GladsonAndrade sorry I forgot the curly braces, so it won't eager evaluate, `onChange={e => { setValue(e.target.value); handleSubmit(); }} `

Comment: so what might be the best solution

Comment: yes its proper now but it will not call handleSubmit function

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that pressing all keys will actually enter a value on your input, there is no need to have the extra `onKeyPress` event

```
const handleSubmit = async (value) => { 
  if (value === "") return; 
  let response = await axios.get(https://api2-4ofagodxfq-uc.a.run.app/locality?stateName=KARNATAKA&districtName=BANGALORE&pinCode=${value});
  console.log(response);
  if (response.status === 200) {
    setLocations(response.data); 
  }
  // do the rest
}

const handleChange = (e) => {
  const { value } = e.target;
  setValue(value);
  handleSubmit(value);
} 

return <input 
  type="text" 
  onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
/>
```

Comment: I am guessing `handleSubmit` requires the updated state as well?

Comment: let handleSubmit = async () => {
    if (value === "") return;

    let response = await axios.get(`https://api2-4ofagodxfq-uc.a.run.app/locality?stateName=KARNATAKA&districtName=BANGALORE&pinCode=${value}`);
    if (response.status === 200) setLocations(response.data);
  }

Comment: Oh, and where does `value` come from?

Comment: value comes from text box

Comment: eg: 560001 and so on

Comment: @GladsonAndrade I have updated my code. You should pass the values of the text box into your handleSubmit function

Comment: still no result

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with `handleSubmit()`? That is because the sample you have given me does not return any data, or do anything else

Comment: <select >
      {locations.map((location, index) => {
        return <option key={index}>{location}</option>
      })}
    </select>

Comment: Iam displaying the result in a dropdwn

Comment: did you do `setLocations(response.data)`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => handleSubmit(), [value]);

<input type="text" onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle both events from another function, and just add this on the `onChange`:

```
// In this method you are able to call anything you need
// So here we are going to set the value and then call the submit
setOnChange = (e) => {
  setValue(e.target.value);
  handleSumbit();
}

// So Here you only use one the setOnChange method
<input type="text" onChange={setOnChange}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place `setValue()` inside `handleSubmit()` method block, then call `handleSubmit` only:

```
<input type="text" onChange={handleSubmit} />
```

Then your `handleSubmit` method will be like:

```
// es6 syntax
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
// handle submit code comes here
setValue(e.target.value) // call setValue here
}
```

If you will need to call `setvalue` first, then place it above the `handleSubmit` code.

Comment: still its not displaying proper output